# What is the MIME type for properties files?

Tags: java, properties, mime-types

What is the MIME type for properties file?

Here is a list of all the files with different extensions but here I could not see any MIME type for the properties file.

[Mime Types](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml)

I have a properties file in my scripts folder and I am trying to read it in another scripts. When run as simple HTML file and a script file it works properly but when I put it in my web application which uses Spring MVC, its not able to read the properties file.

The error I get is

No media type found for ServletContext resource [Messages_en.properties] -returning 404.

Please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Apache [HTTPd's Mime type list](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types) which is probably the most extensive you can find, there is no definition for properties files.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but generally `text/plain` works well with properties files.

Comment: httpd's MIME list is a bit web-content biased. There are not many `.properties` files hosted as common web site content :)

Answer (score 21):

Commonly used is `text/x-java-properties`. E.g. project MoinMoin uses that.

Answer (score 9):

According to [IANA Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) which is the most authoritative source, there is no standard MIME type for Java Properties files.

Apache HTTPD / Subversion MIME type lists (which are referenced in other answers as the one from [@nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582594/nico)) are simply a copy of IANA's.

> [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) specifies that Media Types (formerly known as MIME types)
> and Media Subtypes will be assigned and listed by the IANA. (Source [IANA Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml))

Anyway, I've to agree with [@Ondra Žižka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145989/ondra-%C5%BDi%C5%BEka) that a few non-authoritative - but relevant - sources (like [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSyntaxColoring) and [CaCert.org](http://wiki.cacert.org/HelpOnParsers), for instance) are seemingly converging onto the `text/x-java-properties` type, which is correctly using the `x-' prefix.

There is not a dozen places where this MIME type is used, though.